# Multiple Reports share same sub-report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, bids

I was given about 5 reports to develop and all of them had two sections that were identical for all reports. The rest of the report was unique to each one. So I took the same sections and turned them into sub-reports. Then of course in the main reports I added a sub-report link to the section reports respectively. I already realized benefit as had to make font changes etc. and doing it once was far better than 5 times. These reports are being built in BIDS and are working perfectly. I then took the rdl files and imported them into CRM 2011 the product where they will ultimately be used from.

It is here that my sub-report links break. In crm 2011 I can only choose ONE parent report for the sub reports. So if I set Master1 as the parent report for the two subs then Master1 will run flawlessly. However Master2-3-4-5 will run with the error Subreport could not be shown. If I set Master2 as the parent then Master2 will run flawlessly but 1,3,4,5 will fail?

Googling results in people suggesting to relink to the parent report....which is not my problem here.

I really hope I am just doing something wrong and that this isn't a limitation of CRM 2011.

TIA

JB

> Final Solution Based Upon Guido Preite Answer

So I created sub-reports in CRM for every report that needed them. However all sub-reports in CRM uploaded from the same rdl file. A bit of a mgmnt pain as stated by Guido but that is where we are at in CRM 2011 so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subreports can have only one Parent, it's a limitation of CRM 2011.

You can always create 5 identical subreports, I know will be more difficult to maintain but is the only solution (you can always create a batch file to create the other 4 rdl files when you updated the subreport)

Comment: OK What about hooking the report button. We already are since there are over 100 reports and we have a tree structure to group them. What are your thoughts about dynamically changing the parent based upon the report selected?

Comment: changing the parent requires the report to be saved/published, and probably the users have no the rights to perform this action but only to execute them.